# SHPS and SPHS inequality using monounary algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

Let $A_n = \{(1,\ldots,n) , f \}$ where $f(i) = (i+1)$ if $i \neq n $ otherwise $f(n) = 1$.
This describes a mono unary algebra.
The proof for $HPS \neq SPHS$ I know uses metabelian groups and was published by 
George Bergman in Algebra Universalis. 
Here I need to prove $SHPS \neq SPHS$ for the class of mono unary algebra  $R$ = { $A_p$ | where $p$ is a prime.}

I do not seem to make a start using the above algebra.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: I was reading D. Pigozzi's paper in which he classified all the 18 different operators. I was having trouble understanding his proof for $SPHS \neq SPHS$. My prof suggested me to prove for this first which might help me for the general case.

Comment: What can you show? Can you calculate D(R) where D is some combination of the class operators?

Comment: Also, why do you call the algebra non-cyclic?

Comment: Ohh.. I guess it can be cyclic. I had some other notion of cyclic algebras in my mind.

Comment: The only subalgebras of $A_n$ are $\varnothing$ and $A_n$ itself. The empty set does not contribute anything, so you are really down to showing $SHP\neq SPH$ for the class $R$.

Comment: Yeah.
Suppose I take $A_3$ and $A_5$ But I get $A_3 \times A_5$ in SPH but I get $A_{15}$ in SHP. Although they are isomorphic but different algebras. Does it suffice ?

Comment: No; S is not just the class of subalgebras, it's the class of algebras that are isomorphic to some subalgebra; likewise, P is the class of algebras that are isomorphic to a product. So "isomorphic but different" does not suffice.

Comment: I know you've said that you don't think you'll get good answers in math.SE. Have you actually *tried*? These are reasonably basic, though cast in language that a lot of people are not familiar with. It seems the consensus is that you should be trying there (possibly making the questions a bit more accessible if you are afraid people will not be familiar with the concepts on a cold reading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only subalgebras of $A_p$ are $\varnothing$ and $A_p$. I claim that the only homomorphic images of $A_p$ are $A_p$ and the one-element algebra.

**Note:** there was an arithmetical error in the following paragraph. Fixed.

Indeed, let $\Phi$ be a congruence on $A_p$ that contains a pair $(a,b)$ with $a\neq b$. Applying $f$ sufficient times, we get a pair $(1,k)\in\Phi$, $1\lt k\leq p$. If $k=p$, then applying $f$ we get $(2,1)$ so $(1,2)\in\Phi$, and so after applying $f$ we again we obtain $(i,i+1)\in\Phi$ for all $i$, and since $\Phi$ is an equivalence relation, it is the total relation. If $2\leq k \lt p$, then there exists $n$, $2\leq n\lt p$, such that $nk\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Applying $f$ $(n-1)k$ times to $(1,k)$, we obtain a pair whose second entry is $1$, and whose first entry is congruent to $(n-1)k$ modulo $p$. Since $nk\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, then $(n-1)k\equiv 1-k\equiv p+1-k\pmod{p}$, so we have shown that the pair $(p+1-k,1)\in\Phi$. On the other hand, applying $f$ $p-k+1$ times to $(1,k)$ we obtain $(p-k+2,1)\in\Phi$, so we get $(p-k+1,p-k+2)\in\Phi$ and so we must again have that $\Phi$ is the total congruence.

Therefore, $H(R) = R\cup\{A_1\}$. Since a product that contains copies of $A_1$ is isomorphic to either $A_1$ or one which contains no copies of $A_1$, we conclude that $PH(R) = P(R)\cup\{A_1\}$.  So $SPHS(R) = SP(R)\cup\{A_1\}$. The subalgebras are isomorphic to disjoint unions of (an arbitrary number of) copies of $A_k$s and $\mathbb{N}$, where $k$ is squarefree. Indeed, if $k=p_1\cdots p_r$ is a product of distinct primes, then by taking $A_{p_1}\times\cdots\times A_{p_r}$ and considering the subalgebra generated by $(1,\ldots,1)$, we obtain an element of $f$-order $k$, and so we get an algebra isomorphic to $A_k$; hence, all such $A_k$ are subalgebras of products of elements of $R$. Also, by taking the product $\prod A_p$ over all primes and the subalgebra generated by $(1,1,\ldots)$ we obtain an element of infinite $f$-order, which is essentially the same as $(\mathbb{N},s)$. Taking the subalgebra generated by a finite collecion of such generators in distinct components gives the disjoint union. So all described algebras are in $SP(R)$. Conversely, given a subalgebra of a product of elements of $R$, we can partition it into $f$-orbits; an element $(a_i)$ has $f$-order $n$ if and only if the lcm of the $f$-orders of the $a_i$ is $n$, so the finite $f$-orbits of $R$ must be of squarefree order (since those are the possible orders of the components); and infinite orbits give copies of $(\mathbb{N},s)$.

So $SPHS(R)$ consists of disjoint unions (possibly empty) of copies of $A_k$s for $k$ squarefree (including $k=1$), and $(\mathbb{N},s)$.

However, $PS(R)$ contains $A=\prod A_p$, with the product over all primes, and I claim that a homomorphic image of this algebra is the disjoint union of $A_4$ and $A_1$, proving that $SHPS(R)\neq SPHS(R)$.

Indeed, partitioning $A$ into disjoint $f$-orbits, define the congruence $\Phi$ which restricted to the subalgebra generated by $(1,1,\ldots)$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$) yields the congruence such that $\mathbb{N}/\Psi\cong A_4$ (identifying $a\sim b$ if and only if $|a-b|$ is a multiple of $4$), and that identifies all other elements of all other $f$-orbits into a single point. Then $A/\Phi\cong A_4\coprod A_1$.

Comment: You should claim a subhom of A is isomorphic to A_4 union A_1. (Although I think I see that the union is also in H(A).) Also, I suspect this question and answer more appropriate for math.se, in my humble opinion.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2014.04.15

Comment: @Gerhard: Fair enough on your final comment; but I'm not sure I understand the first part.

Comment: I have two issues on this. 1. Which operation did you use here "we obtain the pair $(p-k+2,1)\in \Phi$, and so we must have $(k,p-k+2)\in \Phi$"
2. How do you show $A=\prod A_p$ has homomorphic image as disjoint union of $A_4$ and $A_1$

Comment: 1. $\Phi$ is a congruence, hence it is both a subalgebra of $A_p\times A_p$, **and** an equivalence relation; if $(p-k+2,1)\in\Phi$, and $(1,k)\in\Phi$, then we must have $(k,p-k+2)\in\Phi$ by symmetry and transitivity. I applied $f$ to get $(p-k+2,1)$.   **2**. I **showed** how: mod out by the congruence $\Phi$ defined in the last paragraph.

Comment: There was an arithmetical error *following* the sentence you ask about; I've fixed the argument.

Comment: @Arturo Thanks. I hope I will be spared of negative votes down there. I went to your profile and found out that your advisor was Prof Bergman. I was reading one of his paper on SHPS and HSP inequality.The one where he uses groups of transalation and rotations to prove the inequality. Would you like to have some discussion on that ? Although I must warn you that some of my reasonings/doubts may sound silly coz m still an undergraduate student reading some advanced math.

Comment: It is more a matter of exposition.  Now that I have reread it, I find less problem with it.  If I were concluding with A and explaining it, I might go a little more slowly, or indicate with more clarity how to produce A_4 union A_1.  My initial (mild) objection stemmed from the impression that you were taking a homomorphic image of a subalgebra of A: you aren't, but it is easy for me to get the wrong impression, and I have seen this material before.  I can't think of a good way to improve the exposition though.  Gerhard "Not To Mention Other Students" Paseman, 2014.04.17

Comment: Arturo and many others familiar with this level of universal algebra often participate on math.stackexchange.  If you @anurag decide to ask similar questions on MathOverflow, I recommend prefacing with a little background, e.g. "I'm a third year undergraduate with a little linear algebra background trying to go through paper X, and teaching myself universal algebra out of text Z.  How do I approach Y?"  It will then be clear that you aren't a graduate student asking others to do your work, and you will be redirected more gently.  Gerhard "With Less Downvotes As Well" Paseman, 2014.04.17

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Slight correction: I am not currently participating in math.SE, and have not for quite a while.

Comment: @Arturo, apologies for the misrepresentation.  Hopefully your reasons for degree of participation are cleaner than mine.  I am glad to see your writing on MathOverflow.  I hope I am not wrong in my estimation of universal algebraic knowledge of the present math.SE participants.  Gerhard "Will Use A Different Tense" Paseman, 2014.04.17